# How to display all time slots between two times

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel application in which I need to display all time slots between 9AM to 3AM on the basis of 15 minutes interval.
the time slots does not contain no date, only times format like (AM and PM)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you carbon `CarbonPeriod`

```php
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;


$period = new CarbonPeriod('03:00', '15 minutes', '14:00'); // for create use 24 hours format later change format 
$slots = [];
foreach($period as $item){
    array_push($slots,$item->format("h:i A"));
}

return $slots;
```

---

as per your req. you need to use like this

```php
$today =  today()->format('Y-m-d') . " 2:00 PM";
$tomorrow =  today()->addDays('1')->format('Y-m-d')  . " 3:00 AM";
$period = new CarbonPeriod(new Carbon($today), '15 minutes', new Carbon($tomorrow));
$slots = [];
foreach ($period as $item) {
    array_push($slots, $item->format("h:i A"));
}
```

it retrun

```php
[
    "02:00 PM",
    "02:15 PM",
    "02:30 PM",
    "02:45 PM",
    "03:00 PM",
    "03:15 PM",
    "03:30 PM",
    "03:45 PM",
    "04:00 PM",
    "04:15 PM",
    "04:30 PM",
    "04:45 PM",
    "05:00 PM",
    "05:15 PM",
    "05:30 PM",
    "05:45 PM",
    "06:00 PM",
    "06:15 PM",
    "06:30 PM",
    "06:45 PM",
    "07:00 PM",
    "07:15 PM",
    "07:30 PM",
    "07:45 PM",
    "08:00 PM",
    "08:15 PM",
    "08:30 PM",
    "08:45 PM",
    "09:00 PM",
    "09:15 PM",
    "09:30 PM",
    "09:45 PM",
    "10:00 PM",
    "10:15 PM",
    "10:30 PM",
    "10:45 PM",
    "11:00 PM",
    "11:15 PM",
    "11:30 PM",
    "11:45 PM",
    "12:00 AM",
    "12:15 AM",
    "12:30 AM",
    "12:45 AM",
    "01:00 AM",
    "01:15 AM",
    "01:30 AM",
    "01:45 AM",
    "02:00 AM",
    "02:15 AM",
    "02:30 AM",
    "02:45 AM",
    "03:00 AM"
]
```

ref link https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-period

Comment: I appreciate it .., based on your solution , it is $period = new CarbonPeriod('03:00', '15 minutes', '09:00');

Comment: But my requirement is $period = new CarbonPeriod('02:00 PM', '15 minutes', '03:00 AM');

Comment: When i use "new CarbonPeriod('02:00 PM', '15 minutes', '03:00 AM')" it returns empty array

Comment: what my expectation is look like below

02:00 PM
02:30 PM
03:00 PM
03:30 PM
04:00 PM
04:30 PM
"     "
"     "
"     "
"     "
"     "
"     "
"     "
"     "
"     "
"     "
12:00 AM
12:30 AM
01:00 AM
01:30 AM
02:00 AM
02:30 AM
03:00 AM

Comment: ok, but my end time is 3 AM, that it is the problem

Comment: start time is 03:00PM and ending time is 02:00AM

Comment: I think no, as you know the end time is AM , means next day, so it is not possible using this code.

Comment: @LbAbid there will be no different if it next day or same day and if you want both in diffrent day then you need to add date also with time

Comment: Thanks for your response, what my point is that time from 2PM to 3AM , here 3AM is going to be tomorrow,

Comment: @LbAbid i added as per your need check that

Comment: Yes, this is what i was talking about, as 3AM is going to be tomorrow, we need to add one next date

Answer (score 2):

Here is a framework agnostic function

```
 /**
         * get a list of hours btw two range
         *
         * @param int  $lower  start hours in secondes
         * @param int  $upper  end hours in secondes
         * @param int  $step   hop btw hours in seconde
         * @param null $format output hours format
         *
         * @return array with hours range interval  
         * Exemple of use: // Every 30 Minutes from 8 AM - 5 PM, using Custom Time Format:  hoursRange( 28800, 61200, 60 * 30, 'h:i a' );
         */
       function hoursRange($lower = 0, $upper = 86400, $step = 1800, $format = 'H:i')
        {
            $times = [];
    
            if (empty($format))
            {
                $format = 'H:i';
            }
    
            foreach (range($lower, $upper, $step) as $increment)
            {
                $increment = gmdate('H:i', $increment);
                list($hour, $minutes) = explode(':', $increment);
    
                $date = new \DateTime($hour.':'.$minutes);
    
                $times[(string)$increment] = $date->format($format);
            }
    
            return $times;
        }
```

Example of use with output:

```
hoursRange(0, 86400, 1800, 'H:i')

array:48 [▼
  "00:00" => "00:00"
  "00:30" => "00:30"
  "01:00" => "01:00"
  "01:30" => "01:30"
  "02:00" => "02:00"
  "02:30" => "02:30"
  "03:00" => "03:00"
  "03:30" => "03:30"
  "04:00" => "04:00"
  "04:30" => "04:30"
  "05:00" => "05:00"
  "05:30" => "05:30"
  "06:00" => "06:00"
  "06:30" => "06:30"
  "07:00" => "07:00"
  "07:30" => "07:30"
  "08:00" => "08:00"
  "08:30" => "08:30"
  "09:00" => "09:00"
  "09:30" => "09:30"
  "10:00" => "10:00"
  "10:30" => "10:30"
  "11:00" => "11:00"
  "11:30" => "11:30"
  "12:00" => "12:00"
  "12:30" => "12:30"
  "13:00" => "13:00"
  "13:30" => "13:30"
  //etc .......
]
```